# Which consumes less memory a Webview or a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

Please see the picture. I have an application that shows data in the form of list but it is a WebView.My application size got increased and it is also creating a lot of data.

So if i convert all the webview to list view then will it reduce the size and does it make any sense to do so?

Or Please suggest me any other way to display data in list that reduce the size.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that all you are going to display is scroll-able list of text sections - `ListView` probably consume much less memory then loading similar content to `WebView`.   no doubt about that.

also, if you decide to go for `ListView` -  make sure you are following all important guidelines and design patterns to optimize memory and improve performence, such as using the [ViewHolder design pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html), handling [recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) properly, and so on..

Comment: Cleared my doubt! I really appreciate that.

Comment: I have a webview in which there are list of questions and on clicking that question user navigate to another webview that has answer, so it is efficient to put all the answers in textview?

Comment: I don't see why not..   you can open on click a new fragment/activity disaplying TextView fills the entire screen wrapped inside a scroll view (in case the content will be longer the screen size)